# PyQGIS Export table with Replace all selected raw field values by displayed values option

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, export, save

I have a table with multiple fields with widget types configured (value map, checkbox, date/time).

What I need is to export this table in a geopackage, using this in a PyQGIS script, using the "Replace all selected raw field values by displayed values".

```py
rutaBase = QgsProject.instance().absolutePath()
rutaGpkg = rutaBase + '/geopackage.gpkg'
table = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('tblActuaciones')[0]

opt = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
opt.layerName = 'exported_table'
opt.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
opt.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(table, rutaGpkg, opt)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: sip.wrappertype cannot be converted to qgis._core.FieldValueConverter in this context
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `opt.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()` instead of `opt.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter` as it's a class not an enum

I've tested below code and it works without failure/crash (QGIS 3.16 on Ubuntu 18.04). The only difference with your script are: did not change in options `actionOnExistingFile`, set `driverName` explicitly to GPKG and use the class like explained in 1st part of my initial answer.

```py
source_layer = iface.activeLayer() # Using a shp point as an input
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'GPKG'
options.layerName = 'exported_table'
fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()

dest_file_name = '/tmp/out.gpkg'
write_result, error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    source_layer,
    dest_file_name,
    options)
```

Comment: Thanks @thomasg77, but If I do that QGIS crashes...

Comment: This works fine although it overwrites the geopackage file and I've other layers in it. But if I leave the actionOnExsistinFile it works and QGIS does not crashes. The problem is that it only replace the boolean and date fields, but not the value map fields.

Comment: For the "the value map fields" not working, did you try with the GUI before? To be sure if error is QGIS overall or only in PyQGIS.

Comment: Yes, I tried it using the GUI before starting the script just to see if it is possible to do so and it works fine.

Comment: FYI, made an answer related at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389698/problem-with-export-vector-layer-by-pyqgis-in-qgis

Comment: Hey @ThomasG77!
I'm facing the same problem; I can export my layer using the GUI without problem, but with the FieldValueConverter() option, QGIS crashes.
Did you find any way to work around this?
The latest code you provided works... because the converter doesn't make it's way to the options :P
Tried with QGIS 3.16 and 3.20, using either writeAsVectorFormatV2 or writeAsVectorFormatV3