# Exporting Vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, vector-layer, qgsvectorlayer

I found a problem with exporting the vector layer with: *"Replace all selected raw field values by displayed values"* in the PyQGIS script.

The source layer contains a value map for attribute `"value_map"`:

[image]

PyQGIS script:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing
from qgis.utils import iface


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        layer = iface.activeLayer()
        feedback.pushInfo(str(layer))
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( 
            layer=layer,
            fileName='C://Users//001-PC//Desktop//output_layer.json', 
            fileEncoding="utf-8", 
            driverName="GEOJSON",
            fieldValueConverter=QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()
        )
        return {}
```

How can I export layer values with a values map? My script does not work with:

> ```
> fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()
> ```

Exported JSON (script result):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "output_layer",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5514" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1, "text": "aaa", "value_map": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -553020.462518186424859, -1170227.009075149893761 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 2, "text": "sadasd", "value_map": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -553025.836183290113695, -1170234.612239605281502 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 3, "text": "sdasdsad", "value_map": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -553018.004352234653197, -1170230.038907602196559 ] } }
]
}
```

Source layer value map setting:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official doc for `QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter` tells you that it's an "Interface to convert raw field values to their user-friendly value"

The interface has 3 methods, `clone`, `convert` and `fieldDefinition`.

For `convert`,

> Default implementation will return provided value unmodified.

For `fieldDefinition`,

> Default implementation will return provided field unmodified.

So, the solution is to create your own class base on `QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter` to get the expected behaviour. In Python tests in QGIS repo, there is an example `TestFieldValueConverter` implemented https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorfilewriter.py#L68 and called from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorfilewriter.py#L533-L569

I've made an example that take `valueMap` info and report them in the export correctly. I've tested below that should more or less do the job as I did not try it extensively. I just manage `valueMap` here but you will need more code to manage other types of fields when converting from fields values to display values. In current code, I did not try in particular to manage `NULL` values. I've also used `writeAsVectorFormatV2` as `writeAsVectorFormat` different ways to export are deprecated although always working at the moment.

```py
class CustomFieldValueConverter(QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter):

    def __init__(self, layer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter.__init__(self)
        self.layer = layer

    def fieldDefinition(self, field):
        idx = self.layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        editorWidget = self.layer.editorWidgetSetup(idx)
        if editorWidget.type() == 'ValueMap':
            return QgsField(field.name(), QVariant.String)
        else:
            return self.layer.fields()[idx]

    def convert(self, idx, value):
        editorWidget = self.layer.editorWidgetSetup(idx)
        # print(editorWidget.config(), editorWidget.type(), editorWidget.isNull())
        if editorWidget.type() == 'ValueMap':
            valueMap = editorWidget.config()['map']
            dictValueMapWithKeyValueSwapped = {v: k for d in valueMap for k, v in d.items()}
            return dictValueMapWithKeyValueSwapped.get(str(value))
        else:
            return value

layer = iface.activeLayer()

myoptions = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
myconverter = CustomFieldValueConverter(layer)
myoptions.fieldValueConverter = myconverter
myoptions.driverName = 'GeoJSON'
context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
mypath = '/tmp/output.geojson'
write_result, error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, mypath, context, myoptions)

print(write_result, error_message)
```

**Edit**:

A more generic version that should work for all fields. Do not hesitate to make comment about it (only tested with a `ValueMap` sample on my side)

```
class CustomFieldValueConverter(QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter):

    def __init__(self, layer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter.__init__(self)
        self.__formattersAllowList = ["KeyValue", "List", "ValueRelation", "ValueMap"]
        self.layer = layer
        self.__mFormatters = {}
        self.__mConfig = {}
        self.__mCaches= {}
        
        for i, field in enumerate(layer.fields()):
            setup = field.editorWidgetSetup()
            fieldFormatter = QgsApplication.fieldFormatterRegistry().fieldFormatter(setup.type())
            if fieldFormatter.id() in self.__formattersAllowList:
                self.__mFormatters[i] = fieldFormatter
                keysValue = setup.config()['map']
                dict_target = {}
                for j in keysValue:
                    dict_target.update(j)
                self.__mConfig[i] = {"map": dict_target}

    def fieldDefinition(self, field):
        if not self.layer:
            return field
        idx = self.layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        editorWidget = self.layer.editorWidgetSetup(idx)
        if idx in self.__mFormatters:
            return QgsField(field.name(), QVariant.String)
        else:
            return field

    def convert(self, idx, value):
        formatter = self.__mFormatters.get(idx)
        if formatter is None:
            return value
        if self.__mCaches.get(idx) is not None:
            cache = self.__mCaches.get(idx)
        else:
            cache = formatter.createCache(self.layer, idx, self.__mConfig.get(idx))
            self.__mCaches[idx] = cache
        return formatter.representValue(self.layer, idx, self.__mConfig.get(idx), cache, value);

    def clone(self):
        return FieldValueConverter(self)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

myoptions = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
myconverter = CustomFieldValueConverter(layer)
myoptions.fieldValueConverter = myconverter
myoptions.driverName = 'GeoJSON'
context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
mypath = '/tmp/output.geojson'
write_result, error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, mypath, context, myoptions)

print(write_result, error_message)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your soulution works well.

Comment: Hi @ThomasG77, I am trying to make your solution work with a Value Relation type, but I get errors considering the 'map' keyword. I searched a bunch, but can't figure out how to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I used @ThomasG77 solution and modified my script. Script is working well now:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsField,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing
from qgis.utils import iface


class CustomFieldValueConverter(QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter):
    def __init__(self, layer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter.__init__(self)
        self.layer = layer

    def fieldDefinition(self, field):
        idx = self.layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        editorWidget = self.layer.editorWidgetSetup(idx)
        if editorWidget.type() == 'ValueMap':
            return QgsField(field.name(), QVariant.String)
        else:
            return self.layer.fields()[idx]

    def convert(self, idx, value):
        editorWidget = self.layer.editorWidgetSetup(idx)
        # print(editorWidget.config(), editorWidget.type(), editorWidget.isNull())
        if editorWidget.type() == 'ValueMap':
            valueMap = editorWidget.config()['map']
            dictValueMapWithKeyValueSwapped = {v: k for d in valueMap for k, v in d.items()}
            return dictValueMapWithKeyValueSwapped.get(str(value))
        else:
            return value

class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        layer = iface.activeLayer()
        myconverter = CustomFieldValueConverter(layer)
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( 
            layer=layer,
            fileName='C://Users//001-PC//Desktop//output_layer.json', 
            fileEncoding="utf-8", 
            driverName="GEOJSON",
            fieldValueConverter=myconverter
        )
        return {}
```