# Using FieldValueConverter() in PyQGIS to export table with displayed values option (ValueRelation), get ValueRelationCache error

Tags: pyqgis, valuerelation

I'm trying to export the content of various tables and use displayed values (stored in a ValueRelation) instead of the raw value.

---

Following the comments, I realized I had to create the FieldValueConverter class. I tried to do that using an [existing code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389783) (from @ThomasG77) that works well for ValueMap, but I fail to make it work for ValueRelation. My general idea was to recover the content of the ValueRelation distant table and format it to mimic the content used in the ValueMap method that works. As I can't find reliable examples of this and easily get confused with the cookbook, I'm guessing I'm not going the right way.
Anyway, the content of the variables seems to be OK, but in the final stage (end of "convert" method), I get this error :

> TypeError: unable to convert a C++
> 'QgsValueRelationFieldFormatter::ValueRelationCache' instance to a
> Python object

```
class CustomFieldValueConverter(QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter):

    def __init__(self, source_layer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter.__init__(self)
        self.__formattersAllowList = ["KeyValue", "List", "ValueRelation", "ValueMap"]
        self.source_layer = source_layer
        self.__mFormatters = {}
        self.__mConfig = {}
        self.__mCaches= {}
        
        for i, field in enumerate(source_layer.fields()):
            setup = field.editorWidgetSetup()
            fieldFormatter = QgsApplication.fieldFormatterRegistry().fieldFormatter(setup.type())
            if fieldFormatter.id() in self.__formattersAllowList:
                self.__mFormatters[i] = fieldFormatter
                if fieldFormatter.id() == "ValueRelation":
                    coucheRef = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(setup.config()['LayerName'])[0]
                    colRefID = setup.config()['Key']
                    colRefVal = setup.config()['Value']
                    map1 = []
                    map2 = {}
                    for k in coucheRef.getFeatures():
                        map2[k[k.fields().indexFromName(colRefID)]] = k[k.fields().indexFromName(colRefVal)]
                    for key,value in map2.items():
                        map1.append({value:key})
                    keysValue = map1
                elif fieldFormatter.id() == "ValueMap":
                    keysValue = setup.config()['map']
                #print(keysValue)
                dict_target = {}
                for j in keysValue:
                    dict_target.update(j)
                self.__mConfig[i] = {"map": dict_target}
                #print('Config['+str(i)+'] :'+str(self.__mConfig[i]))
    
    def fieldDefinition(self, field):
        if not self.source_layer:
            return field
        idx = self.source_layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        editorWidget = self.source_layer.editorWidgetSetup(idx)
        if idx in self.__mFormatters:
            return QgsField(field.name(), QVariant.String)
        else:
            return field
    
    def convert(self, idx, value):
        #print('self: '+str(self)+' - idx: '+str(idx)+' - value: '+str(value))
        #print(self.__mConfig.get(idx))
        formatter = self.__mFormatters.get(idx)
        #print(formatter)
        if formatter is None:
            return value
        if self.__mCaches.get(idx) is not None:
            cache = self.__mCaches.get(idx)
        else:
            cache = formatter.createCache(self.source_layer, idx, self.__mConfig.get(idx))
            self.__mCaches[idx] = cache
        return formatter.representValue(self.source_layer, idx, self.__mConfig.get(idx), cache, value);
    
    def clone(self):
        return FieldValueConverter(self)


source_layer = iface.activeLayer() # Using a shp point as an input
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()

myconverter = CustomFieldValueConverter(source_layer)
options.fieldValueConverter = myconverter
#myoptions.driverName = 'GeoJSON'

options.driverName = 'GPKG'
options.layerName = 'exported_table'
#options.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()
context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
dest_file_name = 'E:\\TMP\\Geofluence_Export\\Geofluence.gpkg'
write_result, error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
    source_layer,
    dest_file_name,context,
    options)
```

Comment: Oh!
I really thought there was a builtin PyQGIS function that mimicked the GUI option. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I just edited my question following some efforts to make it work...

Comment: Not sure who put the bounty but already edited the cited answer from myself to be generic (see Edit section from the answer) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389698/problem-with-export-vector-layer-by-pyqgis-in-qgis/389783#389783

Comment: Hi @ThomasG77, as I stated, I used your edited code, but I bump into the cited error when I work on data that have Value Relations. 
TypeError: unable to convert a C++ 'QgsValueRelationFieldFormatter::ValueRelationCache' instance to a Python object
This happens at this step:
cache = formatter.createCache(self.source_layer, idx, self.__mConfig.get(idx))

Comment: @ThomasG77, using your code, I actually get an error at line 16, considering the 'map' item. It works perfectly with ValueMap, but fails with ValueRelation. This is why I tried the shenanigans to mimic the ValueMap structure in the code up there... while I'm sure there is a better way to approach this.