Exporting Display Values Instead of Relation Values from a QGIS Database Layer to a GeoPackage
I'm developing a QGIS plugin that exports selected layers from a QGIS project into a GeoPackage format. These layers are database layers where certain fields have relation values stored in the database. For example, a field might store an integer value (e.g., 1) that corresponds to a string value (e.g., "Netzebene 1") through a relation in the QGIS project.
In QGIS, these integer values are displayed as human-readable strings due to the relation set up in the layer. However, when I export the layer to a GeoPackage, the plugin exports the underlying integer values (e.g., 1) instead of the human-readable strings (e.g., "Netzebene 1") that are shown in the QGIS attribute table.
What I want to achieve:
I want the plugin to export the displayed values (e.g., "Netzebene 1") instead of the raw relation values (e.g., 1).
Here’s what I’ve tried:
I used the QgsExpressionContext and added the layer and project scopes using QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer) and QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()).
I attempted to manually map these values using Python dictionaries, but this approach is not scalable or maintainable.
Despite my efforts, the exported GeoPackage still contains the raw integer values rather than the displayed strings. Additionally, I encountered several issues and errors while trying to correctly set up the QgsExpressionContext for retrieving the displayed values.
    """Export only selected fields to GeoPackage."""
    # Mapping-Tabelle für normdurchmesser___mm
    normdurchmesser_mapping = {
        0: 'Nicht definiert',
        2: 'DN_100',
        3: 'DN_150',
        4: 'DN_200',
        5: 'DN_300',
        6: 'DN_400',
        7: 'DN_500',
        8: 'DN_600',
        9: 'DN_800',
        13: 'DN_700',
        10: 'DN_900',
        11: 'DN_1000',
        12: 'DN_1200',
        14: 'DN_1100',
    }

    # Überprüfe die Existenz und die Typen der gewünschten Felder im Layer
    layer_fields = layer.fields().names()
    missing_fields = [old_field_name for old_field_name, _ in fields_to_export if old_field_name not in layer_fields]

    if missing_fields:
        QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            self.tr("Fehler"),
            self.tr(f"Die folgenden Felder fehlen im Layer '{layer.name()}': {', '.join(missing_fields)}")
        )
        return

    # Erstelle eine temporäre Schicht mit nur den gewünschten Feldern
    geometry_type = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer.wkbType())
    temp_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"{geometry_type}?crs={layer.crs().authid()}", "temp_layer", "memory")

    temp_layer.startEditing()
    temp_layer_data_provider = temp_layer.dataProvider()

    # Füge die neuen Felder hinzu
    new_fields = QgsFields()
    for old_field_name, new_field_name in fields_to_export:
        old_field = layer.fields().field(old_field_name)
        if old_field:
            if old_field_name == 'normdurchmesser___mm':
                new_field = QgsField(new_field_name, QVariant.String, old_field.typeName(), old_field.length(), old_field.precision())
            else:
                new_field = QgsField(new_field_name, QVariant.String, old_field.typeName(), old_field.length(), old_field.precision())
            new_fields.append(new_field)

    temp_layer_data_provider.addAttributes(new_fields)
    temp_layer.updateFields()

    # Vorbereiten des Ausdruckskontexts
    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalScope())
    context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()))
    context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer))

    # Füge die Features mit den gefilterten Feldern und Geometrien hinzu
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        # Filterung nach spezifischem Feld und Wert
        if filter_field and feature[filter_field] != filter_value:
            continue

        new_feature = QgsFeature(new_fields)
        context.setFeature(feature)
        
        for old_field_name, new_field_name in fields_to_export:
            if old_field_name in feature.fields().names():
                value = feature[old_field_name]

                # Wende das Mapping an, wenn es sich um das Feld "normdurchmesser___mm" handelt
                if old_field_name == 'normdurchmesser___mm':
                    mapped_value = normdurchmesser_mapping.get(value, value)
                    new_feature.setAttribute(new_field_name, str(mapped_value))
                # Hole den angezeigten Wert für 'typ' und 'hydraulische_relevanz'
                elif old_field_name in ['typ', 'hydraulische_relevanz']:
                    field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(old_field_name)
                    display_value = layer.displayField(field_index, feature[old_field_name])
                    new_feature.setAttribute(new_field_name, display_value)
                else:
                    new_feature.setAttribute(new_field_name, str(value))

        # Setze die Geometrie des Features
        geometry = feature.geometry()
        if geometry and not geometry.isEmpty():
            new_feature.setGeometry(geometry)

        # Feature zur temporären Schicht hinzufügen
        temp_layer.addFeature(new_feature)

    temp_layer.commitChanges()

    # Exportiere die temporäre Schicht als GeoPackage
    error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
        temp_layer, output_path, "UTF-8", temp_layer.crs(), "GPKG"
    )

    if error == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print(f"Export erfolgreich nach {output_path}")
    else:
        print(f"Fehler beim Export: {error}")``` 


This might be what you are looking for:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389698/exporting-vector-layer-using-pyqgis
