# QGIS crashed when QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter() was used as fieldValueConverter option

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, shapefile, export, writers

I want to export the PostGIS layer as a shapefile. I need to use replace all selected raw field values with displayed values in QGIS. To do so, I follow [PyQGIS Export table with Replace all selected raw field values by displayed values option](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387017/pyqgis-export-table-with-replace-all-selected-raw-field-values-by-displayed-valu). But my QGIS crashed.

I found the problem in this line (`options.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()`). I do not know what is the reason for this crashing.

This is my complete code.

```py
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'GPKG'
options.fileEncoding = 'utf-8'
options.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_file_name, options)
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem?

Comment: Check also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389698/problem-with-export-vector-layer-by-pyqgis-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple as possible

You need to provide an implementation of `QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter`.

This is better explained in [Problem with export vector layer by PyQGIS in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389698/problem-with-export-vector-layer-by-pyqgis-in-qgis). Check the implementation posted there, to get an improved class to transform the field values according to the editor settings.

With a a very basic implementation, like the following, QGIS will not crash.

```
class CustomFieldValueConverter(QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter):

    def __init__(self, layer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter.__init__(self)
        self.layer = layer

    def fieldDefinition(self, field):
        return field

    def convert(self, idx, value):
        return value

    def clone(self):
        return FieldValueConverter(self)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

myoptions = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
myconverter = CustomFieldValueConverter(layer)
myoptions.fieldValueConverter = myconverter
myoptions.driverName = 'GPKG'
context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
mypath = '/tmp/output.gpkg'
# write_result, error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, mypath, context, myoptions)
# since QGIS 3.20 you can use writeAsVectorFormatV3
error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, mypath, context, myoptions)

print(write_result, error_message)
```

The code works as it is from the console, exporting the active layer. Change the output path, if necessary.